# Why do i get the error Duplicate destination output 'column name' in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

i am trying to insert a data from a query to table.

When i run my insert query i get an error " **Duplicate destination output** ".
Why do i get the error..

Please guide me in this...

Comment: I think Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint is the reason for that..make sure that you are not inserting duplicate data in the primary key column

Comment: Actually my query had two fields in same name..that was the problem..
so while running insert query i got the error.

Removed the duplicate column from query and data got inserted succesfully in the table.

Comment: Good.. in the end data inserted

Answer (score 2):

To clarify... not that each individual table has a field in each with the same name. You are trying to update or append the same field twice. In my case I was using an unmatched query to append new records with employee#, but under append to: it was taking the employee# I wanted to append and also trying to append the field at the end with criteria: Is Null as well

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur when you specify the same column name more than once in an INSERT action such as:

```
INSERT INTO destTable (Column1,Column2,Column2)
  SELECT Column1,Column2,Column3 
  FROM srceTable;
```

The destination column -- Column2 cannot be specified more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate destination output means that you have move than one field (column) with the same name.

Comment: Community wiki for the sake of filling in an answer to quite a useful question.